# How to call an action from another action which is residing in a different controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller which performs certain action. Now, i need  certain functionality (send an email) to happen in middle of the above mentioned controller.

```
try
   {
   using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
      {
       // Add an Accept header for JSON format
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(URLForReportsapi + "InsertOrUpdatePortal", criteria).Result;
       }
      // Throw exception if not a success code.
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      // Parse the response body.
        var pVMRslt = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var pVMRsltDsrlz = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PortalInfoVM>>(pVMRslt);
        portalVMList = pVMRsltDsrlz.ToList();
        var newnumids = portalVMList.Where(c => c.isNewStatus == "NEW").Select(c => c. numid).ToList();
 //-------- Here I need to call another action which is residing inside another controller.
        return PartialView("AddToPortalConfirmation", portalVMList);
   }
```

In the above piece of code before calling the `partialview` I need to call another action which is residing inside a different controller and return back to `PartialView("AddToPortalConfirmation", portalVMList)`

I was trying to do something like this  but this is not working.

```
  var resp = RedirectToAction("Create", "EmailReport", new { numids = newnumids , To = toEmail});
```

In my routeconfig.cs I have

```
  routes.MapRoute(
             null, // Route name
             "EmailReport/Create/{To}/{numids }", // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "EmailReport", action = "Create", To = string.Empty, numids = string.Empty } // Parameter defaults
         );
```

Comment: Generally I would say that if you need to execute the same code from two different controller methods you should extract that code to a common method that both controllers can call. Having said that, it would probably help if you explained *why* you're trying to do this as it would help give a more targeted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
return RedirectToAction("Create", "EmailReport", new { numids = newnumids , To = toEmail});
```

Comment: I cannot have two returns.  return RedirectToAction("Create", "EmailReport", new { numids = newnumids , To = toEmail});                                                                             return PartialView("AddToPortalConfirmation", portalVMList);

Comment: You can have few returns in one action.If you call redirect to action in one of your cases so that action will return the view

Comment: If you want just execute some code in action 2, don't use action, use shared sevice method